# How to implement server-side paging in jqGrid using generic handler

Tags: c#, jqgrid

i'm trying to implement paging for jqGrid. but it's not clear if i can do it using generic handlers in asp.net?

my grid looks like this:

layout:

```
<table id="userGrid" ></table>
<div id="userGridPager"></div>
```

script:

```
grid = $("#userGrid");
        grid.jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost/MyApp/MyHandler.ashx',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Account', 'Deleted', 'Timer'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50, stype: 'text', key: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, editable: true},
                { name: 'Account', index: 'Account', width: 50, editable: false },
                { name: 'Deleted', index: 'Deleted', width: 50, editable: true, sortable: false, align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false} },
                { name: 'Timer', index: 'Timer', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true }                     
            ],                
            rowNum: 15,
            mtype: 'GET',
            pager: '#userGridPager',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Users",
            height: "100%"                
        });
```

MyHandler.ashx:

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
// how can i get here page number?

var users = User.GetAllUsers(); // it's necessary to pass page number and page size to this function
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
context.Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(users));
}
}
```

i understand that i need to pass my data to client so that it will contain page, total, records for jsonReader, but i don't understand how to get page number in habdler. does anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you could have the page number in the query string of the GET request E.g.

`WebApp/MyHanler.ashx?page=2`

How to get query string parameter, you can see here: [How to get the QueryString from an ashx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085952/how-to-get-the-querystring-from-an-ashx-file)